# adding a space after each 4th number/digit Oracle 11G

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, dbms-output

I am trying to get a space into every 4th number/digit (not character). This is what I come up with:

```
  newStudentNumber := regexp_replace(newStudentNumber, '[[:digit:]](....)', '\1 ');
  dbms_output.put_line(newStudentNumber);
```

result:

```
NL 2345 7894  TUE
```

What I actually want:

```
NL 1234 5678 944 TUE
```

My code replaces the number at every 4th place with a spacebar, instead of adding a space like the wanted result above.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What was the original input?

Comment: What do you mean with the original input? The input of the wanted end result or my whole code?

Comment: Kinda saw that one comming ye. regexp_replce = replace. But how to add a space then?

Comment: Yes.. you showed the wanted result and result you are getting but not the input..

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you fully, but I got my input in the top which is :
newStudentNumber := regexp_replace(newStudentNumber, '[[:digit:]](....)', '\1 ');
  dbms_output.put_line(newStudentNumber);

or is that not what you ment?

Comment: I meant input string.. for which the expected output is what you showed.. anyways.. check my answer..

Comment: What's the value of 'newStudentNumber' when `regexp_replace` is called?

Comment: the value of newStudentNumber is NL 12345678944 TUE (before the given input code) and I would like to change it to: NL 1234 5678 944 TUE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex..

```
([[:digit:]]{4})
```

And replace with what you are doing now.. `\1(space)`

> Why yours is not working?

Your regex matches a digit and captures next 4 characters (not only digits). So.. when you do a replace.. the digit which is matched but not captured is also replaced.. and not because it is unable to insert.

Explanation for input = `NL 12345678944 TUE` and regex = `[[:digit:]](....)`:

```
NL 12345678944 TUE   (it will match digit "1" and captures "2345")
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uA8yD8/4)

Comment: When I tried your solution, I get this:
NL 944 TUE

The value of newStudentNumber = NL 12345678944 TUE and I want to change that to NL 1234 5678 944 TUE

Comment: Did you check the demo? did you use `newStudentNumber := regexp_replace(newStudentNumber, '([[:digit:]]{4})', '\1 ');`?

Comment: I checked out the demo ye. I honestly did not understand that, but thanks for providing that demo anyways. I also would like to thanks you for the solution. It works. Thanks alot and I mark your awnser as the right given one. cheers